# How to use RatingStars Vaadin addon

Tags: vaadin

How to use RatingStars Vaadin addon?
I want to use RatingStars addon on all our vaadin pages so that we can get quick feedback from user.
Is there any example available which shows how to use that?

Comment: What have you tried so far: [sources & demo](https://github.com/tehapo/RatingStars), [old wiki](https://vaadin.com/web/teemu/wiki/-/wiki/Main/RatingStars), [dedicated forum](https://vaadin.com/forum/#!/thread/72816/72815)?

Comment: I've seen these links...I used dependency in project but maven couldn't find this jar so it's failing  
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.vaadin.addons</groupId>
 <artifactId>ratingstars</artifactId>
 <version>2.1</version>
</dependency>

Comment: Then I manually downloaded that jar, unzipped it and kept that my source location. But it's still failing for  Failed to execute goal com.vaadin:vaadin-maven-plugin:7.6.1:compile (default) on project vaadin-widgetset: GWT Module org.vaadin.teemu.ratingstars.RatingStars not found in project sources or resources. -> [Help

Comment: Added a more comprehensive answer with the 3 steps required to use an add-on/widget: adding the dependency, compiling the widgetset, specifying the widgetset.

Answer (score 1):

[Using widgets with Vaadin (with or without Maven)](https://vaadin.com/directory/help/using-vaadin-add-ons) usually means you have to do [3 things](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/addons/addons-maven.html) before starting your application:

- adding the widget dependency to your classpath
- compiling the widgetst
- specifying your widgetset

From your description you've already done the first but you had some trouble, so let's take them separately and since you're already using Maven we'll just continue down this road:

**1: Adding widgets**

> I used dependency in project but maven couldn't find this jar so it's failing
>
> ```
> <dependency>
>     <groupId>org.vaadin.addons</groupId>
>     <artifactId>ratingstars</artifactId>
>     <version>2.1</version>
> </dependency>
> ```

Some of the widgets, also known as add-ons, may not be available in the central maven repo, so make sure you [add the Vaadin dedicated repo in your POM](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/addons/addons-maven.html#addons.maven.dependency):

```xml
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>vaadin-addons</id>
        <url>http://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons</url>
    </repository>
    ...
</repositories>
```

Now it should resolve and download your dependency, adding it to the classpath.

---

**2: Compiling the widgetset**

> Then I manually downloaded that jar, unzipped it and kept that my source location. But it's still failing for
>
> ```
> Failed to execute goal com.vaadin:vaadin-maven-plugin:7.6.1:compile (default) on project vaadin-widgetset: GWT Module org.vaadin.teemu.ratingstars.RatingStars not found in project sources or resources
> ```

Now, before you can run your app, you also need to [compile the widgetset](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/addons/addons-maven.html#addons.maven.compiling). If you've generated your project skeleton using the [`vaadin-archetype-application`](https://vaadin.com/maven) everything should be already configured and you simply need to run `mvn package` (or `mvn vaadin:compile` for just the compilation process).

Otherwise take a look at [this sample](https://github.com/vaadin/valo-demo/blob/master/pom.xml) project for a standard `vaadin-maven-plugin` configuration.

**P.S.** Depending on you IDE, you can also use [dedicated IDE plugins](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/gwt/gwt-eclipse.html) for these tasks, but that's up to you.

---

**3: Specifying the widgetset**

Finally, depending on your servlet version and app setup you can define your widgetset location by:

- using the `web.xml` file:

```xml
<init-param>
    <description>Application widgetset</description>
    <param-name>widgetset</param-name>
    <param-value>com.example.MyWidgetSet</param-value>
</init-param>
```

- annotating your UI with `@Widgetset("com.example.MyWidgetSet")`

---

Now you should be able to run your application and see the widget on your screen :-)

Comment: Thanks Morfic, that was a wonderful explanation. I've yet not tried to give dedicated repo but I could see RatingStars component on my app. Issue was because I had not given entry in our *widgetset.gwt.xml . This line was missing.  <inherits name="org.vaadin.teemu.ratingstars.gwt.RatingStarsWidgetset" />. I also did mvn clean install and compile widget again. Now I'll try to integrate it with TextField to take feedback and to store (star rating) it db.

Comment: @ArchanaMundaye no problem, glad I could help. The missing line from the widgetset should be automatically added by `vaadin-maven-plugin` when updating or recompiling the widgetset. This makes it easier when using multiple add-ons because you don't have to know or search for each of the referenced widgetsets. Cheers